# Serialization in C, Beej's guide not understanding why it doesnt work?

Tags: c, sockets, serialization

So I'm doing some reading about Beej's guide and I am using the pack functions to serialize data into a buffer, everything good until I get the following I start running into this behavior.

```
int packetsize = pack(buf, "HH",cinfo->id,cinfo->port);

  int16_t client_id;
  int16_t portnumber;
  unpack(buf, "HH", &client_id,&portnumber);
  printf("LOGIN with id: %" PRId16 "=%d portnumber:%d \n", client_id, cinfo->id, portnumber);
```

Give this output

`LOGIN with id: 0=1 portnumber:1151`

But if I change it just a little bit to this

```
int16_t portnumber, client_id;
unpack(buf, "HH", &client_id,&portnumber);
printf("LOGIN with id: %" PRId16 "=%d portnumber:%d \n", client_id, cinfo->id, portnumber);
```

The output change

`LOGIN with id: 1=1 portnumber:1150`

Do you got any idea of that could be going on here?

Edit 1:

This happens with both HH and hh, it could be memory overrun as [@Artemy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8491726/artemy-vysotsky) suggested  but I'm not sure why it's happening  since they both are of same size, and the buffer is big enough for both of them. The order of the declaration seems to matter although not sure why.

This works

```
int16_t portnumber, client_id;
```

This doesn't work.

```
int16_t client_id, portnumber;
```

Edit 2, this is the struct I'm using

```
typedef struct ClientInfo {
        char name[HOSTNAME_LEN], *ip_address;
        int16_t message_sent, message_received, status, socket, id, port;
        LIST_ENTRY(ClientInfo) clients;
} ClientInfo;
```

Comment: Looks like memory overrun is corrupting something - add temp vars before and after your vars and check the values after read https://gist.github.com/artemyv/eb1f816f9c047f7717351c6cd36f8690, and BTW - why do you need specific format for printing clieint_id - printf uses integer promotion to int - so it should be printed using %d same as portnumer

Comment: Did you try `hh` instead of `HH`?

Comment: could be an aliasing issue

Comment: would it be the problem if there is already a portnumber variable declare somewhere outside the scope of this function let's say a global accessible variable.